# Overbrace is not alligned correctly

Tags: xetex, equations, arrays

Here is an equation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{unicode-math}     


\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

Hello world
\begin{equation}
\overbrace{
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
w \\
\end{array}
\right]}^q =
\overbrace{
\left[
\begin{array}{c c c}
f_x & 0 & c_x \\
0 & f_y & c_y \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
}^M
\cdot
\overbrace{
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
X \\
Y \\
Z \\
\end{array} \right]}^Q
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The thing is that the overbraces are not equally aligned vertically as you can clearly see.
[image]

Comment: You are using a different font, which may be the cause for it. Inserting `\mathstrut` (or even `\strut`) in a cell across all the rows might solve the problem. However, you may which to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) that clearly illustrates your current setup. From there, it may be easier to assess the exact problem source.

Comment: @Werner i have added the MWE.

Comment: This doesn't look like the output that I get when running the code with xe/lualatex from TL2012. Though the TL 2012 output has its own share of problems.

Comment: I opened a bug report at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/241 with a much more *minimal* MWE and the output that I get.

Comment: @Caramdir wow, did not know that i found a bug there.. is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

There's really not much that can be done here with the present XITS Math font. However, the output is much better with TG Termes Math

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{unicode-math}     


\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{TG Termes Math}

\begin{document}

Hello world
\begin{equation}
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
w \\
\end{bmatrix}
}^{\mathstrut q}
=
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
f_x & 0 & c_x \\
0 & f_y & c_y \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}^{\mathstrut M}
\cdot
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
Y \\
Z \\
\end{bmatrix}
}^{\mathstrut Q}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]